# Cannot connect to database

Tags: zabbix

I am getting this error when trying to set up Zabbix to my MySQL database on Ubuntu. They are running on the same VM.

However I am getting this error, and I have not found anything in the log files.

Does anyone know why this would happen or how to diagnose it?

[Zabbix Set Up Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TluG8.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could check whether MySQL listens on that port. If not, you'd have to fix that.

But instead of using the port, why not use the socket if it's all running on the same system? To do so, set the server to `localhost`.